# Display Splunk Timechart in Local Time

Tags: logging, splunk, splunk-query

I have a very simple `timechart` query:

```
index="myIndex" "searchText"
| timechart span=1d
```

The Splunk logs are in UTC, but I need the chart to display the data in local time instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set your Splunk user profile to the desired time zone.